# How to compute for duration in spark-scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 columns which was converted from epoch format:

```
val df2 = df1.withColumn("event_end_ts", from_unixtime($"end_ts"/1000, "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss:ss"))
.withColumn("event_start_ts", from_unixtime($"start_ts"/1000, "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss:ss"))
```

which gives me this:

```html
+----------------------+----------------------+ 
|event_end_ts          |event_start_ts        |
+----------------------+----------------------+ 
|2022/05/24 03:49:01:01|2022/05/24 03:48:50:50| 
|2022/05/24 03:49:00:00|2022/05/24 03:48:51:51| 
|2022/05/24 03:50:03:03|2022/05/24 03:49:05:05|
+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Now,I am trying to get the duration of 2 columns. I've tried this, but it's giving a null results:

```
df2.withColumn("time_diff", (to_timestamp($"event_end_ts") - to_timestamp($"event_start_ts"))/3600)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to cast them to `LongType` first, like this:

```py
df2.withColumn("time_diff", (to_timestamp($"event_end_ts").cast(LongType) - to_timestamp($"event_start_ts").cast(LongType))/3600)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It worked. Although, one issue I've noticed is that the datatype for the even_end_ts and event_start_ts is in string so I have to cast it to timestamp first. Also, on the cast part, I just use `.cast("long")` . But thanks! this is really helpful!